# Error CS0012 The type 'Cliente' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Classe manipulação com EF:

```
ContextEF Contexto = new ContextEF();

public List<Cliente> Listar()
    {
        //var query = from c in Contexto.Cliente
            //          select c;
        return Contexto.Cliente.ToList() ;
    }
```

Onclick da pagina de consulta

```
protected void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientService service = new ClientService();
        var lista = service.Listar();

        gvListacEF.DataSource = lista;
        gvListacEF.DataBind();
    }
```

Erro apresentado:

> Error  CS0012  The type 'Cliente' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'DAO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Comment: Você renomeou essa classe recentemente? Essa dll? Você fez algum merge onde houve conflito de referência?

Comment: Não renomeei nem a classe nem a dll.
Só criei e compilei.

Comment: Você referenciou esse assembly (DAO) no assembly atual?

Comment: Não.
Estou testando recriar o projeto para ver o que eu possa ter feito de errado.

Comment: Esse esse é o problema, você esta fazendo o using desse assembly DAO mas não adicionou a referência no seu assembly atual. Me diga se fazer isso funciona.

Comment: Rapaz, deu certo.
Muito obrigado. Não sabia desse detalhe, estou aprendendo asp.net.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66208/discussion-between-jb-and-gabriel-coletta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou comentando a resposta que foi feita no comentário para retirar ela dos "Sem Resposta"

O problema é que você esta tentando usar um namespace (`using DAO`) de um assembly ainda não referenciado na sua aplicação atual:

Para fazer isso, vá em **Reference > Add Reference... > Projects > Solution** e selecione o assembly desejado (no seu caso o DAO).

Da próxima vez que você fazer um build o erro vai desaparecer.

Para mais detalhes, recomendo o MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx